# Parsing this weird response PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I am getting a JSON mixed array response from an API and I am trying to parse it efficiently but unable to do so

```
  [{"Price":10,"Active":null,"Status":100,"Name":"ID"}]
```

I am unable to access the price, name property.

I am trying a mix of ``` json_decode``json_encode ```tried it using `foreach`

What is the best way to parse this response, (preferably, without looping)

Comment: `preferably, without looping` whats wrong with looping?

Comment: did you see my comment, my code works, but you have to duplicate it, not approximate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um... like this

```
$array = json_decode('[{"Price":10,"Active":null,"Status":100,"Name":"ID"}]', true);

echo $array[0]['Price'];
```

Outputs

```
10
```

See it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9dcef1fb38f2c9e011d2a519038a80c0782723f1)

As I said in the comments, you have to set the second argument to `true` for it to be an array and not an Object, personally I hate using it as an Object.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> **Json Decode**
>
> *mixed* **json_decode**(*string* **$json**[,*bool* **$assoc** = FALSE[,*int* **$depth** = 512[,*int* **$options** = 0 ]]])
>
> Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.
>   Parameters ¶
>
> **ARGUMENTS**
>
> **json** The json string being decoded.
>
> **assoc**  When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.
>
> **depth** User specified recursion depth.
>
> **options** Bitmask of JSON decode options

Comment: Doesn't work,  `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: @zuif - Please click where it says `here` as that is a sandbox with this exact code and does in fact work.  Now if you forget the second argument, of json_decode,  ie `json_decode('....', true)` and you leave that out, it's not my fault, but yours for not reading fully.  Because, indeed the second argument turns in from an object into an array, which you obviously neglected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check code to remove extra spacing around `<?php` or `?>` OR you can can trim response in php.

PHP

```
$decode = current(json_decode(trim($response)));
var_dump($decode->Price);
```

[PHP Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2eee6ab52b39393bfddb0df60b2ecb1f69229ef1)

Comment: i can see the space in question thats why i said, however he wants to get it without loop

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in this response

**without loop**

```
function myfunction($value, $key)
{
  echo "$key". " ". "$value";
}

$a = json_decode('[{"Price":10,"Active":null,"Status":100,"Name":"ID"}]');

   array_map("myfunction",$a);
```

**with Loop**

```
$dataResponse = json_decode('jsonString or response',true);
```

then you iterate over it simply

```
foreach($dataResponse as $key => $value){
   echo $key. " ". $value
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `preferably, without looping`

Answer (score 0):

You can do with

```
  json_decode($str)[0]->Price;
```

First decode from string and then print from first object

[LIVE DEMO](https://eval.in/969755)

Comment: `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: @zuif : if your variable is `$result` then use , `$result[0]["Price"]` or `result[0]->Price`